# MLS - How is differ two MLS Data get from RETS server?

Tags: php, rets

I pulled data from RETS server (Using one MLS) but now I am  confusing ,If I will pull data using another MLS from another RETS server then that data will be differ from previous RETS data.I mean to say if I will pull RETS data from two different MLS then that data will differ or may be same and If differ then how it is differ?How two MLS data is differ is it differ from location wise or any fields are differ?

Please help me.

Comment: I would suggest that you start by better tagging your quesion - why not "mls" for example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MLS Data is a bit goofy. Each MLS Board has it's own design more or less of how they set up their DB.  Each of the fields and columns are going to be different, however you can find a standard set of items on how things are 'supposed' to be formated, so that you can easily consume them.

> if I will pull RETS data from two different MLS then that data will differ or may be same and If differ then how it is differ?

They will differ in options offered, along with field names.  However you should (assuming you have written a dynamic way of viewing and consuming) be able to consume them without much of a hitch.  (Keeping in mind each MLS has a set of rules for: offset, limit, getting images ect..)

> How two MLS data is differ is it differ from location wise or any fields are differ?

Fields are different, Rules for displaying the data is different, limit and usage is different.. it also depends what service the MLS is using to distribute their data.

Hopefully this is helpful to you.

Comment: I have just started with RETS recently and it looks like a total hack job. Not looking forward to it one bit, there is absolutely NO consistency to the data I'm getting from our mls server. Sometimes 1/0 is used, sometimes "Yes/No", field names aren't consistent in RETS Connector, and there are these "csv" values that are sometimes missing one side of a quote. And I love how most of the listing descriptions are in ALL CAPS FOR EMPHASIS! :)

Answer (score -1):

IT possible Different MLS Server Having Different MLS Data information and You have to Manage That one Because location wise that information can be changed